# StartSSL and MySql

Tags: mysql, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've used StartSSL to generate my certs.  At this point, I have a root key (ca.pem), an intermediate key (sub.class2.server.ca.pem), and a general key file (named it generalkey.key).  Now I have no idea what to do.  When I generated the key and pem files myself, following instructions from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/creating-ssl-certs.html, I ended up with three files, ca-cert.pem, server-cert.pem, and server-key.pem.  I assume what I downloaded that they called the root key is what I use for ca-cert.pem, and their intermediate key is server-cert.pem.  What do I use for server-key?  Would generalkey.key be the file I should use?  Can I rename it to a pem file?  Or do I need to do something else?

How do I generate the client files?

Thank you.

-Nick

Comment: Huh? You got 3 files. ca-cert.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem. You shouldn't need anything else. ca-cert.pem is the ca certificate. server-cert.pem is the server certificate and server-key.pem is the server key. server-cert.pem is not an intermediate key, it's your server key.

Comment: I've received many files from StartSSL, and I'm not really sure what to do with them.  I'm not sure if they map 1 to 1, or if I need to use them to generate other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out start ssl was able to help me.  In case anyone ever is trying to use start ssl to secure mysql, here's what I did.

concatenate ca.pem and sub.class2.server.ca.pem to create the ca-cert.pem.  Then use the key file and crt file they give you as the server key and cert.